# HDMI does not work on ubutnu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I had problem with ubuntu 18.04, it was stuck on loading... now I have fixed that with reisntaling nvidia drivers (using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-465 proprietary, tested) and added nomodeset to grub. now it is loading. Graphic card is geForce GTX 950M in lenovo  ideapad 700 15isk.

Problem is, when I plug hdmi monitor in settings it does not show options for it on devices/display card and on details card graphics are unknown. I run `sudo journalctl  -b 0 | grep HDMI`  and got

```
Jun 04 17:48:00 XXX kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Jun 04 17:49:01 XXX kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for 
Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

Any help?

Comment: Reinstalling Nvidia drivers *and* adding `nomodeset` makes no sense, at all. Please remove it and try again. Don't forget to disable Secure Boot in UEFI. Also 465 is incorrect, you should install 460 and supposedly 465 no longer supports old cards.

Comment: I installed 460 drivers, still no settings for hdmi monitor

Comment: You need 460, remove nomodeset and disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: I did that, and if I remove nomodest, it does not load. I can hear welcome  sound, but screen is blank.

Comment: Again, (1) you MUSTN'T have nomodeset as it overrides all drivers and consequently disables any support for external monitors. (2) You MUST disable Secure Boot in UEFI because it prevents loading the Nvidia proprietary drivers. I'm not sure you understand all this and...

Comment: ... How exaclty are you installing the Nvidia drivers? Hopefully not from the Nvidia binaries. Please use additional Drivers. If you have been installing any other way you may need to remove/purge them all before correctly installing the recommended version.

Comment: I did that, i purged all nvidia drivers that were installed, revmove nomodeset and did update-grub. Secureboot was disabled. I installed drivers from additional drivers card and now I got black screen when trying to boot

Comment: Did you by any chance installed Ubuntu in BIOS/Legacy mode?

Comment: No, i was working fine, i installed steam and some game, after that it broke. Now I can only get to working on one screen with nomodeset, without thst it just goes black on boot

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu, not 18.04 but 20.04 and make sure to enable automatic installation of 3rd party drivers, codecs, firmware, etc. This assures the proper drivers are installed from the start.

Comment: Not an option. For now, I am looking ways to fix it without reinstall it